# Child gameObject doesn't move with the parent gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent, gameobject

So, right now I'm working on a Unity game where if you click on an item, it will become the child of the click object.  The click object is also the child of the player and moves with the player, but the object that gets clicked (making it the child of the click object) just stays where it is. Even if you move. I don't know why it doesn't move with the player, does anyone know why?

Comment: maybe [static](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) is checked?

Comment: Does it have a rigidbody attached?

Comment: Is another script setting the transform.position of the child every frame?

Comment: None of these are the issue. It has a rigidbody 2d that is set to dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** nest (parent) `Rigidbody2D` (=> physics based objects) under another object.

It doesn't behave as you expect since the Physics engine doesn't care about the hierarchy of the objects.

If you need a rigidbody to follow another object rather use [**Joints**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints2D.html)!